# How to refer to resources folder in debug mode?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to debug my web application in Jetty using gradle. I have some of my property files in source code. Since these files are not copied to WAR, I used the below code to use `resources` folder,

```
sourceSets.main.resources { 
    srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]; include "**/*.*" 
}
```

This includes properties files in WAR. But when I debug in eclipse, it points to `classes` folder which doesnot contain properties folder. How to make debug to point to `resources` folder?

Build.gradle:

```
war {
        doFirst {
            def propertyFile = file "src/main/java/com/properties/about/About.properties"
            def props = new Properties()
            propertyFile.withReader { props.load(it) }
            println "Before setProperty:"
            println props.getProperty('releaseDate')
            props.setProperty('releaseDate', new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss'))
            propertyFile.withWriter { props.store(it, null) }
            println "After setProperty:"
            println props.getProperty('releaseDate')
        } 
        buildDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "gradleBuild/" + project.name)
    }
```

Comment: `these files are not copied to WAR`, what are the files, how does the file layout look like?

Comment: After adding this, 'sourceSets.main.resources { 
    srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]; include "**/*.*" 
}'  WAR file contains all  the files with all extensions, say .properties, .xsd. But the java class files are repeated. My intention was to include all the files with all extensions. Without this, the files are not added to WAR

Comment: And the layout, I am not having separate resources folder for the properties file. All types of files are included in the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating `src/main/resources` folder and included all files other than class files in it. Say, I created `properties\sample.properties` and referred this path in code. Now there occurs no issue while debugging and also when deployed as WAR. By having `resources` folder all the files are included in WAR without having to modify `build.gradle`